# Card view emoji and text not aligning

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem creating cardView with emoji and text not aligning. Here are the pictures and code:

[image]

```
<github.ankushsachdeva.emojicon.EmojiconTextView
                    emojicon:emojiconSize="36dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:linksClickable="true"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:textColorLink="#5BCFF2"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="19dp"
                    android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Content"
                    android:padding="16dp" />
```

I tried increasing the emojiconSize without changing the textSize, the emoji size remain the same.
I decrease the textSize without changing emojiconSize, text and emoji both decreasing at the same time.
Headache to solve this. Please help. Thanks

Comment: did you tried adding gravity to your textview?

Comment: I would ask the author of the library

Comment: Thought so..@Zielony